# How can I cut off a RSS feed description after 2 sentences using preg_split?

Tags: php

I want to take a description of a RSS feed located in $the_content and cut it off after 2 full sentences (or 200 words and then the next full sentence) using preg_split.

I tried a couple times, but I'm way off. I know what I want to do, but I can't seem to even start on something to make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Proper splitting of HTML is very tricky, and not worth doing with regular expressions. If you want HTML, something like [DOM text iterator](http://pornel.net/source/domlettersiterator.php) will be useful.

1. Convert description to text:

   ```
   $text = html_entities_decode(strip_tags($html),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
   ```
2. This will take first 200 characters (200 words is a bit too much for a sentence, isn't it?) and then look for end of sentence:

   ```
   $text = preg_replace('/^(.{200}.*?[.!?]).*$/','\1',$text);
   ```

You could change `[.!?]` to something more sophisticated, e.g. require space after punctuation or require that there's no punctuation nearby:

```
  (?<![^.!?]{5})[.!?](?=[^.!?]{5})
```

`(?=…)` is positive assertion. `(?<!…)` negative assertion that looks behind current position. `{5}` means 5 times.

I haven't tested it :)